# Ruby: array of hashes from textfile

Tags: ruby, arrays

Lets say I have text file like this:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
...
```

I want to read it into data structure like this:

```
h[1] = { "a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3 }
h[2] = { "a" => 4, "b" => 5, "c" => 6 }
h[3] = { "a" => 7, "b" => 8, "c" => 9 }
```

At first it seems easy. I use:

```
 lines=File.read(ARGV[0]).split("\n")
 h=[]
 lines.each ( |x| h << x.split())
```

And completely stuck at this point. How can I convert h to array of hashes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
lines = File.readlines(ARGV[0])
lines.map { |l| x = l.split(/\s/).map(&:to_i); { 'a' => x[0], 'b' => x[1], 'c' => x[2] } }
```

Comment: You made this a little harder than it needs to be. `File.readlines` already does the splitting on newlines (and works in Windows). `split` splits on whitespace without any arguments.

Comment: Thanks @Max. Adding that. Note that `File.readlines` leaves the `\n` at the end of each line, but `to_i` discards it

Answer (score 4):

```
def parse(filename)
  File.readlines(filename).map do |line|
    Hash[('a'..'c').zip(line.split.map(&:to_i))]
  end
end

parse(ARGV[0]) # => [{"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3}, {"a"=>4, "b"=>5, "c"=>6}, {"a"=>7, "b"=>8, "c"=>9}]
```

Comment: Ah yes, the functional approach.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Gem you can use for this: [`smarter_csv`](https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv)

Put this in your Gemfile:

```
 gem 'smarter_csv',  '1.0.5'
```

and then:

```
 require 'smarter_csv'
 result = SmarterCSV.process('/tmp/bla.csv', 
         {:col_sep => ' ', 
          :headers_in_file => false, 
          :user_provided_headers => ['a','b','c'],
          :strings_as_keys => true
         }
 )
  => [{"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3}, 
      {"a"=>4, "b"=>5, "c"=>6}, 
      {"a"=>7, "b"=>8, "c"=>9}] 

 result[0]
  => {"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3}
```

See also: [`smarter_csv` README](https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use:

```
require 'pp'

ary = []
DATA.each_line do |li|
  ary << Hash[%w[a b c].zip(li.split)]
end

pp ary

__END__
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Running that I get:

```
[{"a"=>"1", "b"=>"2", "c"=>"3"},
 {"a"=>"4", "b"=>"5", "c"=>"6"},
 {"a"=>"7", "b"=>"8", "c"=>"9"}]
```

Change `ary` to `h` if you want that to be your variable name.

If you're reading from a file use `File.foreach('file/to/read.txt')` instead of `each_line`.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is not as elegant as Christian's:

```
base = ['a','b','c']
h=[]
i = 0 # traverses the a,b,c
j = 1 # traverses the lines of the hash h

File.open(ARGV[0]).each_line do |line|
  arr = line.split(' ')
  arr.each do |x|
    if !h[j].nil?
      h[j][base[i]] = x.to_i
    else # first entry in the hash should be set like this:
      h[j] = {base[i] => x.to_i}
    end
    i += 1;
  end
  i = 0
  j += 1
end
p h[1]
p h[2]
p h[3]
```

output:

```
{"a"=>"1", "b"=>"2", "c"=>"3"}
{"a"=>"4", "b"=>"5", "c"=>"6"}
{"a"=>"7", "b"=>"8", "c"=>"9"}
```

I started from j = 1 since that's what the OP asked for, even though it would probably make more sense to start from zero.